# Al abrir ventana hija (Toplevel) que no se pueda acceder a la padre, un estilo de pop Up

Tags: python, poo, tkinter

Estoy tratando de crear una ventana padre y una hija, la idea es que si aprieto cualquier opción del menú, esta se abra una ventana hija que esta en otro archivo de código

Tengo mi archivo principal: Padre.py

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
import shutil
from hija import *

root=Tk()
root.state("zoomed")
root.title("Ventana Padre")
root.iconbitmap("Imagenes/jupyter.ico")
root.geometry("+0+0")

class Jupyter:

    def salirApp():
        valor=messagebox.askokcancel("Atencion", "¿Estas seguro que deseas Salir?")
        if valor==True:
            root.destroy()

    #-----------------------Munu------------------------------
    barraMenu=Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=barraMenu, width=300, height=300)

    archivoMenu=Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
    archivoMenu.add_command(label="Ventana Hija", command=arrancaVentanaHija)
    archivoMenu.add_separator()
    archivoMenu.add_command(label="Salir", command=salirApp)

    #Barra principal
    barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Archivo", menu=archivoMenu)

    miFrame=Frame(root)
    miFrame.pack(fill="both", expand="True")
    miFrame.config(bg="#F6F6F6")
    miFrame.config(width="1280", height="676")
    miFrame.config(bd=10) 
    miFrame.config(relief="groove") 
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", salirApp)

    imagenAdn=PhotoImage(file="Imagenes/adn.png")
    Label(miFrame, image=imagenAdn, bg="#F6F6F6").place(x=0, y=0)
    imagenTitulo=PhotoImage(file="Imagenes/titulo.png")
    Label(miFrame, image=imagenTitulo, bg="#F6F6F6").place(x=450, y=50)
    
    root.mainloop()
```

La venta hija la tengo en otro archivo el cual llamo hija.py

```
import tkinter as tk

def arrancaVentanaHija():
    otra_ventana = tk.Toplevel()
    otra_ventana.title("Ventana hija")
    # Este es solo para decoracion
    etiqueta = tk.Label(otra_ventana, text='Mensaje de prueba')
    etiqueta.pack()

    otra_ventana.mainloop()
```

El problema esta en que quiero que mientras arranque la ventana hija, la padre no se pueda manipular, como una especie de popUp.
Vi la opción de ocupar transient de esta forma:

```
import tkinter as tk

def arrancaVentanaHija():
    otra_ventana = tk.Toplevel(root)
    otra_ventana.title("Ventana hija")
    # Este es solo para decoracion
    etiqueta = tk.Label(otra_ventana, text='Mensaje de prueba')
    etiqueta.pack()

    otra_ventana.transient(root)
    otra_ventana.mainloop()
```

Pero me dice que root no esta definido:

```
NameError: name 'root' is not defined
```

Como puedo dejar que root sea leíble de todos lados?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes pasarle "root" como argumento en archivoMenu.add_command.

**1º Aceptar el argumento en arrancaVentanaHija()**

```
def arrancaVentanaHija(root):
    otra_ventana = tk.Toplevel(root)
    otra_ventana.title("Ventana hija")
    # Este es solo para decoracion
    etiqueta = tk.Label(otra_ventana, text='Mensaje de prueba')
    etiqueta.pack()

    otra_ventana.transient(root)
    otra_ventana.mainloop()
```

**2º ¿Cómo pasarle un argumento si command=funcion sólo acepta la referencia de la función?**

Podemos pasarle la referencia de una objeto lambda, el cual contendrá la llamada de arrancaVentanaHija(root)

```
archivoMenu.add_command(label="Ventana Hija", command=lambda: arrancaVentanaHija(root))
```

Por cierto, supongo que has recortado el archivo Padre.py porque le faltaría el constructor y la variable root en la clase Jupyter.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la pronta respuesta, me gustaría si me aclararas un poco si lo he hecho bien. No tenia creado el constructor y lo he puesto así: 

def __init__(self):
  self.root = root

Luego le pase el comando:

archivoMenu.add_command(label="Ventana Hija", command=lambda: arrancaVentanaHija(root))

Y luego en el archivo hija.py me pedía un argumento así que lo envié de esta forma:

def arrancaVentanaHija(root):
    
Veo que así me funciona pero me gustaría saber si cree bien el constructor con la variable y si es la forma correcta de llamarlo

Comment: @DaniloAndrusco Sii, se me olvido añadirle el root en arrancaVentanaHija(root)) :( ya esta editada la respuesta. Por lo demás todo bien, supongo que habrás llamado a Jupyter(). Si ya te funciona, perfecto!    Pd: sería mejor práctica si hicieras  def __init__(self, root): self.root = root Y así cuando lo utilices en la clase pongas self.root en lugar de root. Para ello además deberás llamar a Jupyter como Jupyter(root). Es difícil explicarlo en estos mensajes, pero esto último lo puedes obviar

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias por tu tiempo